# How to get the names of all variables that have more than two unique values in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to get the names of all variables that have more than two unique values in a list.
For the data frame below I used:
`length(unique(dat$category)) ; length(unique(dat$birds)) ;length(unique(dat$wolfs));length(unique(dat$snakes))` 
But obviously it gave me the results per selected variable.Any Ideas?

```
dat <- read.table(text = " category birds    wolfs     snakes
                   yes        3        9         7
                   no         3        8         4
                   no         1        2         8
                   yes        1        2         3
                   yes        1        8         3
                   no         6        1         2
                   yes        6        7         1
                   no         6        1         5
                   yes        5        9         7
                   no         3        8         7
                   no         4        2         7
                   notsure    1        2         3
                   notsure    7        6         3
                   no         6        1         1
                   notsure    6        3         9
                   no         6        1         1   ",header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try:

```
names(dat)[sapply(dat, function(x) length(unique(x))>2)] #in this example, all the variables have length of unique values >2 
#[1] "category" "birds"    "wolfs"    "snakes"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `duplicated` for that

```
check <- sapply(dat, function(x) any(duplicated(x)))
check
# category    birds    wolfs   snakes 
#     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
```

To then extract the names `names(dat)[check]`